# no space after xtable in latex

Tags: xetex, luatex, xtable

Hello Community I am using print(xtable) for 2 different tables, the spacing is ok in one [image: table] 
**and in the other table there is not enough space between rows**. [image: enough space]
I am calling the directory same way too `\input{C:/Users/seyma/TP/tp.R/tp.R5 - Copy/MLR.AUC.tex}` or `\input{C:/Users/seyma/TP/tp.R/tp.R5 - Copy/GLM.AUC.tex}`. and the code is identical too.
How to fix this? any help will be appreciated.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{AUCs of Multinominal Model} 
    \label{tab:MLR.AUC}
    \begingroup\fontsize{12pt}{11pt}\selectfont
    \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
        \hline
        & MLR.1 & MLR.2 & MLR.3 \\ 
        \hline
        Urb \& Rrl & 0.685 & 0.684 & 0.678 \\ 
        Educ.0 \& Educ.1 & 0.678 & 0.678 & 0.671 \\ 
        CCP.0 \& CCP.1 & 0.663 & 0.663 & 0.658 \\ 
        Sex.0 \& Sex.1 & 0.668 & 0.670 & 0.667 \\ 
        Bench.Mark & 0.660 & 0.658 & 0.657 \\ 
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: I can see no difference between your two tables. The spacing is much too tight in both.

Comment: (1) I agree with Bernard (2) This is due to the bad choice of  `\fontsize{12pt}{11pt}` that I guess that is not made by xtable (3) The use of `\hline`  does not help, but  `xtable` knows how to make tables using `booktabs` that allow a better spacing. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11604+xtable+booktabs) for some examples.